# Google Chrome extension Cross Domain XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have created a simple extension for Google Chrome but I have issues with accessing dictionary API. The API runs on different domain that the one on which my extension runs.
I have read all StackOverflow threads on this topic but was unable to resolve this problem.

I have added the address of the API to permissions. It was not working, so I replaced it for the purpose of testing by `http://*/*`. I have the following `manifest.json`:

```
{
"name": "web2memrise",
"version": "0.3",
"manifest_version": 2,
 "permissions": ["http://*/*"],
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
    "css": ["style.css"]
}],
"web_accessible_resources": ["script.js", "jquery.min.js"]
}
```

The Javascript function in which I make the API call is:

```
function translateCallback(json){
    var translations = "";
    for( var phrase of json){
        translations += ", "+phrase.text;
    }
    translations = translations.substring(2).replace(", ", "\t")
    popupContent(translations)
}

function translate( l1, l2, phrase){;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://deu.hablaa.com/hs/translation/"+phrase+"/"+l1+"-"+l2+"/", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = translateCallback
    xhr.send();
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
home:19 GET http://nxtck.com/as.php?zid=48360&clbk=nextperf net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENTloadScript @ home:19window.onload @ home:37
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://deu.hablaa.com/hs/translation/solution/fra-eng/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.lefigaro.fr' is therefore not allowed access.
script.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: json[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I've never answered a question before, apologies if my formatting is atrocious.

Firstly, "xhr.onreadystatechange = translateCallback" is the root of the issue, perhaps causing a small snowball effect of errors. So I made a small change to resolve that. I also changed the order of your function parameters to match the order they are used in the url (makes it a little easier for me to follow).

The api docs state that everything must be lowercase, so I added that to your translate() function. Also added responseType = json. Any malformed parameters will result in 404 error thus resulting in "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" errors, so that's something to be aware of.

Here's what I ran in my background.js, also worked in a content script.

```
function translateCallback(json) {
    var translations = "";
    for (var phrase of json) {
        translations += ", " + phrase.text;
    }
    translations = translations.substring(2).replace(", ", "\t");

    /* console for testing only */
    console.log(translations);

    /* uncomment this, commented out for testing */
    //popupContent(translations);
}

function translate(phrase, l1, l2) {
    var url = "http://deu.hablaa.com/hs/translation/" + phrase + "/" + l1 + "-" + l2 + "/";

    /* api requires lowercase */
    url = url.toLowerCase();

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);

    /* added json for responseType */
    xhr.responseType = 'json';

    /* onload function added */
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            translateCallback(xhr.response);
        }
    };

    /* error function added */
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        /* error */
    };

    /* this was causing problems and need to be removed */
    //xhr.onreadystatechange = translateCallback

    xhr.send();
}
translate('blume', 'deu', 'eng');
```

That all worked for me, so I expect it will for you :)